# Burrows Wheeler Transform (BWT)

Tags: algorithm, decode, decoder, burrows-wheeler-transform

I am having difficulties in grasping the decode algorithm for the Burrows Wheeler transform (BWT.) I've done reading online and went through some sample code, but, they all seem to be using a 'primary index' to decode an encoded string.

My question is, how can we decode a BWT encoded string like 'rdacraaaabb' to its original 'abracadabra'.

Some sample code would be wonderful.

Comment: wikipedia has some 'code' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform

Comment: Tried it. Wikipedia's python code doesn't compile :( And it's quite cryptic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3559-PHP-Compress-and-decompress-data-using-BWT-and-MTF.html.

Comment: It's a great link! Only issue is, the program can only decode the data it encoded itself. It cannot decode generic BWT data.

Comment: Chunk size doesn't matter. The issue is while encoding the BWT, the program puts a special EOF character and it relies on that to decode it. I was wondering if there was a way to decode it if we don't have a EOF character.

Comment: I tried voting. I'll accept it but it's not the best answer. :(

Comment: Working on it now. Will post results if I have any success.

Comment: @DeepHouse The EOF character is required to be able to decode the BWT encoded word, I think. (Why would it otherwise *be* there, since it is not at the end in the encoded string)?

Answer (score 0):

The inverse part is the easiest part of the algorithm: create cumulative histograms and retrieve values based on their rank.

You can find a complete block compressor/decompressor based on the BWT here: http://code.google.com/p/kanzi/source/browse/java/src/kanzi/transform/BWT.java